# Deleting records from one table if all records are equal to a specific value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, subquery, sql-delete

**Student Table**

```
Student_ID  School          Home State  Grade      Age
85          Washington St   Colorado    Junior     22
90          Washington St   Washington  Senior     23
81          Oregon          California  Junior     21
21          Washington      Washington  Sophomore  21
```

**Attendance Table**

```
Student_ID  Active  Date
85          N       9/22/20
85          N       9/21/20
81          Y       9/22/20
81          N       9/21/20
```

Hey in an Oracle DB if I want to go clean up the table with the student's information by seeing who is still an active student. By sorting by Student_ID in the attendance table I want to find students if they have all values for which active = 'N'. If all values for each student active = 'N' then I know they are no longer a student, I would like to delete the records from the Student table (student 85). However, if only on records for each student has Active = 'Y', then I won't delete anything with that student as I know they're still active (student 81). What would the best way to go about this, I have tried to use the all operator but I've been unable to get the results desired. Below is the query I have been trying to use.

```
DELETE /*+ parallel (a) */ FROM STUDENT a 
WHERE ( a.student_ID  = ALL
(SELECT /*+ parallel (b) */ b.student_id, b.active FROM attendance b WHERE b.active = 'N'));
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses `not exists`:

```
delete from student s
where not exists (
    select 1 from attendance a where a.student_id = s.student_id and a.active = 'Y'
)
```

This also deletes students that have no attendance at all. If that's not what you want, then you can use a correlated subquery instead:

```
delete from student s
where (
    select min(active) from attendance a where a.student_id = s.student_id
) = 'N'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for 'Y' rows using aggregation:

```
DELETE 
FROM STUDENT
WHERE student_ID IN
 (
   SELECT student_id
   FROM attendance
   GROUP BY student_id
   HAVING MAX(active) = 'N' -- no Y for this student
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NOT Exists
```

will be best option here, as guessing you have to handle some huge tables.
I second GMB's 1st query.